# Can someone explain what this c++ code does? Having trouble with structures.

Tags: c++, structure

Can someone explain this code to me? I've been given this example and I think my explanation is a little off.

```
struct n {
    struct n *r;
    int          k;
};

struct n *f(struct n *x, int q)
{   
    if (!x || (x->k == q)) {
       return x; 
    } else {
       return f(x->r, q);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your explanation? Let's start there.

Comment: a pointer of struct n represents a node to a forward list. method f searches from a node top down for value q. however that code sample is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

---

Declaring data type

```
struct n { //Declares a Struct data Type
    struct n *r; //First member's type:pointer to any variable of the same type (struct n)
    int       k; //Second member: an integer value
};
```

Assuming you already know what a struct is, if you don't, check [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/)

---

Declaring and defining function

```
return type = pointer to a variable of **struct n** type => [struct n*]  
function name => [f]  
first parameter =  pointer to a variable of **struct n** type => [struct n* x]   
second parameter = an integer value => [int q]
```

---

```
struct n *f(struct n *x, int q) //function's "head"
{   
    if (!x || (x->k == q)) { //checks if the pointer is not NULL or if the struct that x points to, has its integer 'k' equal to the integer 'q' passed as a seccond parameter
       return x; //if that is the case, return that pointer 
    } else {
       return f(x->r, q); //if that is not the case, check again with the next value
   }
}
```

Check how [recursive functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D2N36Up4/) work to understand why the function calls itself
Additionally, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NobHlGUjV3g) will help you get the whole idea, about why would a struct have a pointer to itself

Answer (score 0):

This is very obfuscated code to get a node in a singly linked list that has the value "q".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct n {
    struct n *r; // pointer to the NEXT element in the list
    int          k; // the value of the current element in the list
};

// note I moved the location of * to exemplify the return is a pointer, doing this doesn't change the function
struct n* f(struct n *x, int q)
{
    if (!x || (x->k == q)) {
        return x; // if the pointer is null or the element's value is q return it
    } else {
        return f(x->r, q); // recursivly call the function until we get an element that matches
    }
}

int main() {
    n foo;
    foo.k=0; // position 0 in the list will also have the value 0
    foo.r=new n; // link the node at position 0 to another new node
    foo.r->k=1; // the new node is at position 1 in the list and has value 1
    foo.r->r=0; // terminate the list by saying that the new node doesn't point to any other nodes i.e. null

    n* elementZero = f(&foo,0); // call the function f and get a pointer to the element that has the value 0
    n* elementOne = f(&foo,1);
    n* elementNotInList = f(&foo,2);

    cout<<"foo[0] "<<elementZero->k<<endl; // omiting null check on pointer
    cout<<"foo[1] "<<elementOne->k<<endl; // omiting null check on pointer
    if(!elementNotInList)
    {
        cout<<"There was no element in the list with that value hence the pointer is "<<elementNotInList<<endl;
    }
}
```